# Filter EntityCollection to get only visible PushPins from map.targetBounds?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am using v7 javascript Bing Maps API!

I have an EntityCollection which contains PushPins. I want to get all the PushPins from the current viewport of map, or from within the map.getTargetBound()?

I have something like this, where Geocode.pinLayer is an EntityCollection object and i've already added an id property to the PushPins objects. pushPin.getVisible() unfortunately for me only checks if the pin is on the map or not, not in the viewport:

```
`var visiblePins = [];
        for(var i=0; i<Geocode.pinLayer.getLength(); i+=1){
            if(Geocode.pinLayer.get(i).getVisible()){
                visiblePins.push(Geocode.pinLayer.get(i).id);
            }
        }
        return visiblePins;`
```

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be very easy unless I misunderstood your question.

1. Get current map view(port): [Map.getBounds()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx).  You get a LocationRect object back.  Let's call it `LocationRectViewPort`.
2. Get location of your Pushpin: [Pushpin.getLocation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427615.aspx). You get a Location object back.  Let's call it `PushPinLocation`.
3. See if `PushPinLocation` is inside `LocationRectViewPort`.  Use [LocationRect.contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427621.aspx), for example:

> ```
> if(LocationRectViewPort.contains(PushpinLocation))
> {
>      // Do stuff
> }
> ```